# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I get this error when I try call `onClick` function `<li onClick={this.props.selectItem.bind(this, item.id)} key={index}>`:

```
export default class List extends React.Component {
    getState(props) {
        const key = props.params.key;
        return {
            key : key,
            list: Store.getList()
        }
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = this.getState(props);
    }

    renderList(item, index) {
        return <li onClick={this.props.selectItem.bind(this, item.id)} key={index}>{item.name}</li>;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.state.list.map(this.renderList.bind(this))}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

And I have parent:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    selectItem(item) {
        alert(item);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <List selectItem={this.selectItem} params={someParams} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a few things wrong here. 1) Don't use `getState()` for initial state when using ES6 classes. Set the state direction (`this.state = {};`) in your `constructor()`. 2) How are you using the `<List />` component? If you could post that code it would help greatly in figuring out what's going on.

Comment: @rossipedia, I changed my question.

Comment: @rossipedia, I use `getState()` for update states from store on `onChange()`. It's not `getInitialState`. Sorry, I'm new in ES6

Comment: I was unable to reproduce that error. See this example: http://jsbin.com/yeheha/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass in `null` instead of `this` for `bind` when binding methods passed in from parent components.

So `this.props.selectItem.bind(this, item.id)` becomes `this.props.selectItem.bind(null, item.id)`.

Comment: That's not necessarily true at all.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor,  do a this.renderList = this.renderList.bind(this);